# C# : menustrip control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, menustrip

i have a menustrip with two items british and SI , there are the items names , i want to display some text when ever one of them is clicked , i tried that with that code but nothing happens when i click the item on the menu

```
    private void unitToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (britishUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked==true)
        {
            label21.Text = "lb/hr";
            label22.Text = "lb/FT3";
        }
        else if (sIUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked==true)
        {
            label21.Text = "Kg/hr";
            label22.Text = "Kg/m3";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty unclear.  Did you implement the Click event for the menuitem?

Comment: They are called "imperial" units, as they are also used in another of other nations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the:

```
CheckOnClick = true;
```

property set.  You aren't showing the code on how you are toggling the check values, since it seems that if you select British Units, you presumable are unchecking SI Units.

Something like this, maybe:

```
private void unitToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (britishUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked==true)
    {
        sIUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        label21.Text = "lb/hr";
        label22.Text = "lb/FT3";
    }
    else if (sIUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked==true)
    {
        britishUnitToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        label21.Text = "Kg/hr";
        label22.Text = "Kg/m3";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , your code is the one i just did , for me the labels was hidden from the control so i had to write label21.show(); and label22.show();